# Can Remote Desktop Services API be used to create you're own sessions

Tags: winapi, windows-7, remote-desktop

I want to create my own 'remote desktop connection' tool with some user friendly options.  Can the '**Remote Desktop Services API**' be used to do this?

Comment: is this related to .NET somehow? Is the API a managed API?

Comment: It's not managed.  It's native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [Remote Desktop ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). If you'd like to get a better idea of how you can use this control, you can find a number of applications around that use it -- e.g. [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/).